# Do vectors need to work in translated coordinate systems as well as rotated coordinate systems?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

In the Feynman Lectures on Physics, Chapter 11, section 5 (http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_11.html#Ch11-S5) Feynman states: "In order for it to be a vector, not only must there be three numbers, but these must be associated with a coordinate system in such a way that if we turn the coordinate system, the three numbers “revolve” on each other, get “mixed up” in each other, **by the precise laws we have already described**."

**Is there not an equivalent requirement for when we translate the coordinate system?**

If we ignore y and z components and just focus on x components, so we can describe each point in our coordinate system using only one number, we have the points:

A(a), B(b), and C(a + b).

In a new coordinate system, translated by α to the right, we have the points:

A(a'), B(b'), C(a' + b').

Substituting into the equation linking the two coordinate systems (x' = x - α), we get:

a' = a - α, b' = b - α, a' + b' = a + b - α

However, it is clear that adding a' and b' gives a' + b' = a + b - 2α, not a' + b' = a + b - α - they don't match.

Is my reasoning here wrong or is there simply no requirement for translations of coordinate systems as there is with rotations?

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

In that context, that is as in linear algebra, vectors are considered "applied" to the origin, therefore we are not interested in translations. In particular the text is referring to a rotation around the $z$ axis.